# How to show transaction on metamask when balance is 0

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js

I'm using ethers.js and trying to call for a method on a contract using

> myContract.myMethod(amount, {"value": ethers.utils.parseEther((price * amount).toFixed(2))});

the toFixed() is not important here (it's only because calculations with multiply and float gives answers like 12.000000002 and it's not passing the validation from the contract

I'm using metamask for the user to interact with the contract, the problem is when I have balance 0, and I'm trying to call for myMethod I get an error: 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value' but I want it to be that metamask will open and show the transaction, and it will be the one that will show the 'insufficient fund' error without getting an error in my code (this is mostly for user-friendly from the metamask UI). I haven't found any answer about it in the ethers.js documentation and I saw some sites that implement this logic somehow (for example https://opensea.io/).

Example how it opens in opensea site:
[image]

Is it possible to do this through ethers.js or any other way?

Thank you.